# Chrome extension that focus on web element when I pass xpath of that element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Chrome extensions. I want to create an extension which focus on web element on browser when I pass the 'xpath' or 'CSS' of that element to the extension and press submit.

Scope of this extension is just to check, whether the xpath or CSS is of that element only or not.

Code which I have tried until now:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#moped-text').focus();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <textarea name="newText"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Comment: I assume this is in a content script?